# What do you call a spike which does not flatten?

Tags: single-word-requests

For a line graph, let's say that you have observed a sudden spike at some point in time and which doesn't flatten. What do you call this? I am calling it an unsettled spike. Are there any other names that suit this more?

Comment: Why would it not just be a spike? Be definition, a spike on a graph is a point of data, from which there was upward movement in the past, and, on the other side, downward movement. To call it *unsettled* doesn't make any sense. A spike remains a spike. If something stops for while and then continues, it's not a spike, but a *plateau*, followed by another increase.

Comment: I think many techies would call it a "transition" or a "level change".  If it keeps going up it would likely be called a "parabola".

Comment: And, of course, let's not forget "hockey stick".

Comment: Please edit your question as suggested by @Conrado in his comment on my answer. Many would consider a *spike* to be a sudden increase followed rapidly by a commensurate sudden decrease, not a sudden increase to a new status quo.

Comment: Actually, if the spike does not flatten then those are some very puncture-resistant tires!

Comment: I would call it an infinite step function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I would call the *sudden spike* to which you refer a **jump**, i.e., a sudden increase in the value of a function from some relatively narrow range of values it once had for some period of time to another relatively narrow range of much larger values that it continued to have for another (long) period of time. From Cambridge:

> **[jump](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jump)**: to increase suddenly by a large amount, e.g., house prices have jumped dramatically;
>   the cost of building the road has jumped by 70 percent.

Comment: In which case I would suggest that "spike" is not really synonymous, suggesting rather a rise _and subsequent fall_. I understand OP to say, however, that the slope of the graph increases suddenly in a region or at a point, and *does not later decrease*. Could we suggest an edit to the question to clarify that? A picture or two would be good.

Comment: @Conrado I agree that an edit (and figure) would definitely help. I believe I am interpreting the OP's question correctly, but interpretation shouldn't be necessary. I've added a comment on the question, as only the OP can clarify.